# Spring Security - conditional WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: spring, security, tomcat

The documentation for Spring Security states that in order to use the Java Config we can extend the `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` class which will set up all nesesarry beans for Spring Security to work. This approach is working fine, the initializer is run automatically and Spring Security is initialized correctly during application startup.

But right now i am facing a scenario when this initialization should be depended on a system property. So i would like to include my initializer class only when some system property is set (for example: `app.enablesecurity=true`) and NOT execute this initializer in any other case.

I failed to come up with any solution for that scenario because:

- In `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` the `onStartup` method is
  marked final so i cannot override it and add a condition
- If i just extend `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` it is
  always automatically picked up by Spring and instantiated (or at least Spring tries to create instance of it, it  may fail), even if i
  declare it as a private/inner/nested class.

So as far as i know the only possibility of conditionally including this initializer is to use cglib/javassist in order to dynamically create a class that extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`.

Is there any other way? Maybe there is some method that will allow me to hide my implementation from being picked up by Spring and run it by hand at a later time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Config Class like this to configure your security behavior

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${app.enablesecurity}")
    private boolean securityEnabled;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (securityEnabled) {
            http.csrf().disable();
            ...
        } else {
            http. ...  
        }
    }
}
```